# R problem, JSON objects in csv file, one per cell:

Tags: r, jsonlite

```
{"received":1588687345,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"sensor","payload":{"time":1588687345,"sensor":[{"type":"temp","unit":"degc","value":20}]}}
{"received":1588687346,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"sensor","payload":{"time":1588687344,"sensor":[{"type":"temp","unit":"degc","value":22}]}}
{"received":1588687346,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"sensor","payload":{"time":1588687346,"sensor":[{"type":"temp","unit":"degc","value":22}]}}
{"received":1588687348,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"sensor","payload":{"time":1588687347,"sensor":[{"type":"temp","unit":"degc","value":28}]}}
{"received":1588687349,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"sensor","payload":{"time":1588687347,"sensor":[{"type":"temp","unit":"degc","value":-667}]}}
```

all the data are in the first column of the csv file. I would like to convert to readable format such as dataframe, and save with write.csv()? Thanks for your help 
[image]

Comment: @Onyambu suggested that I ask this question again, but I couldn't tag him in because of insufficient reputations. if you can't help please don't vote against it.

Comment: How does your readable format looks like? Give an example how your given input should look like as expected output.

Comment: received,  guid,  eventype, time   ,               type, unit, Value;     in a dataframe would be appreciated

Comment: I have added an image description under the question. Thank you

Comment: Solved:    jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df)))

Comment: this method didnt work with "readLines" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(jsonlite)

df <- read.csv("example.csv", header = FALSE)

jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df)))
```